# How to migrate IDs from JOIN table into foreign key column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables in my MySQL database:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `id` char(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`(191))
);

CREATE TABLE `Post` (
  `id` char(25) NOT NULL,
  `authorId` char(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `authorId` (`authorId`),
  CONSTRAINT `Post_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`authorId`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `_PostToUser` (
  `A` char(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `B` char(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `PostToUser_AB_unique` (`A`,`B`),
  KEY `B` (`B`),
  CONSTRAINT `_PostToUser_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`A`) REFERENCES `Post` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `_PostToUser_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`B`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The relationship between `User` and `Post` right now is managed via the `_PostToUser` JOIN table.

However, I want to get rid of this extra JOIN table and simply have a foreign key reference from `Post` to `User`, so I ran this query to create the foreign key:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `Post` ADD COLUMN `authorId` char(25);
ALTER TABLE `Post` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`authorId`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`);
```

Now, I'm wondering what SQL query I need to run in order to *migrate the data* from the JOIN table to the new `authorId` column? If I understand correctly, I need a query that reads all the rows from the `_PostToUser` relation table and for each row:

1. Finds the respective `Post` record by looking up the value from column `A`
2. Inserts the value from column `B` as the value for `authorId` into that `Post` record

Note that I am aware that this changes the relationship from m-n and restricts it to 1-n: *One post can at most have one author. One author/user can write many posts.*

---

I'm basically looking for the **equivalent of this PostgreSQL statement**:

```sql
UPDATE "Post" post
SET "authorId" = post_to_user."B"
FROM "_PostToUser" post_to_user 
WHERE post_to_user."A" = post."id";
```

Comment: Current scheme allows "multiple posts per user" (1) and "multiple users per post" (2). Implementing *I want to get rid of this extra JOIN table and simply have a foreign key reference from Post to User* you will loose 2nd possibility.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that, see the last sentence in the post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ensure that `_PostToUser.A` values are unique (no duplicated values). If exists - edit your data (remove excess records, for example).
2. Execute

```
UPDATE Post, _PostToUser
SET Post.authorId = _PostToUser.B
WHERE Post.id = _PostToUser.A
```

3. Ensure that there is no NULLs in `Post.authorId`